# Modifying NTC thermistor signal

Tags: simulation, thermistor

I have various devices with two wire NTC thermistors for which the curves are known.
I want to add a programmable offset to this thermistor. The lowest the resistance goes down to is about 500 ohms, highest that is needed is around 100k.

I've looked into the following methods:

1. Using two digipots - Their precision is about 20% at lower resistances (e.g. 1k), but about 1% at 100k. This makes it hard to get a precise signal. 200 ohms at higher temperatures is 5C, but the problem occurs at the 1000-2000 ohm range, because here you have essentially up to a 1k error on the 100k pot...
   Another problem is, that the digipots can only accept voltages from Vss to Vdd on the wiper/endpoints, so if a device comes along that uses 12V for sensing then there's a problem.
2. Using resistive optocouplers. The NSL-32 seems like it would be great, except I am in Europe, so these can not be used here, only possible to use in audio equipment, which this is not.
3. Maybe an ADC and DAC combination could be used? Measure the voltage coming from the sensor with an ADC, and then output the same voltage with a DAC? I am guessing it would work if the device is measuring voltage. But again same voltage limitations as on 1 and also the polarity will be important...

Does anyone have a better idea?

EDIT:
Seems like 2) could be done with two H11F1M's and a 12 bit DAC. If my LTSpice simulation is anywhere near correct, then it would give a 0.2-0.3 degree step near 100k resistance if the DAC is used with a 1k current limiting resistor (if I make the current limiter resistor switchable between 1k and 10k, then I get a 0.1 degree precision in the whole range). I guess H11F3M could also be used, as they are cheaper and still fulfil the 500 ohm minimum requirement...
The idea is to fit them close to each other, run both off the same DAC in parallel, measure one constantly with an ADC and use that as feedback for the DAC.
A bit pricy due to the opto's price.

Comment: When you say you want to add an offset, do you mean a resistance offset or a temperature offset?

Comment: The end goal is a temperature offset (as the devices eventually convert the thermistor resistance value to a temperature). But the immediate goal is a resistance offset.

I basically need a floating VCR I think. I want to use a uC to read the existing sensor, and then simulate an arbitrary sensor based on the existing reading.

Treating the devices as black boxes - I don't know how they are reading the resistance. Likely guess is voltage divider into an ADC with the NTC acting as R2, but who knows...